# What is the best solution for a secure login?

Tags: cookies, authentication, system

PHP
My website is almost done, but i'm having some problems with security. Actually, i didn't have problems yet, but i need to prevent. For example, the login system, i'm using cookies/session for it. And as people answered here, cookies are easy to overcome, and it's vunerable.

What is the best way to do a login system, including the passwords and data security?

Also, i'm using cookies for write the names of the users on posts. For example.
(Pretending that the login was successful)

```
$Cookie = $_COOKIE['username'];
$Cookie = $FetchUserNameFromDatabase;

//Then, on posts to write the name of the user, from the cookie.
$DoPost = "INSERT INTO posts (username, message) VALUES ($Cookie, $AnyMessage)";
```

Is this the best way to write the users name on posts, from a cookie value (since after login, the name of the user is saved on a cookie)?

**IF NOT**, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advanced.

**@EDIT**

I forgot to ask. Also, what's the best way to prevent people do a lot of comments (mass-spam)? For example, i do a comment (or a vote, or whatever) and works fine. Then, i do another comment and it blocks me for some time and i can't comment again until this time expires. What's the best way to do it, or at least, what the major sites/forums uses to prevent it?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use session ids? I'd implement a login using a https connection, then assign a sessionid, wich identifies the user against your db. For further reference you won't even need a secure connection anymore.

In case you want to identify a post just use somthing like "SELECT username FROM users WHERE sessid=" . session_id()

Comment: What's the difference of SessionID and a session with a name?

Answer (score 0):

In point of view, you should only use cookie information when you perform an operation that **DOES NOT** change the state of your application; like displaying the User name in the top of a page.

However in every scenario that you application is changing its state like adding a new POST (in your example) you definetly must not trust the client cookies.

To answer "The best way to do it", it depends on what technologies your are relying on.

Edit:

To prevent mass spam you should use the cookie information and the request information the like IP address.